# Local notification repeating every day - iOS

Tags: ios, background, uilocalnotification

I'm using location service in background to update my app every day. In background it parses the XML and sets local notification at 18h, but only if parsed data is different then "No warning". But I'm getting every day notification with same alert body even when I shouldn't. This is how I push notifications.

```
If(![self.city isEqualToString:@"No warning"]){

// We only need 1 notification 
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];

 NSCalendar *gregCalendar = [[NSCalendar alloc]initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];

                NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [gregCalendar components: NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit | NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit fromDate:[NSDate date]];

                [dateComponents setYear:[dateComponents year]];
                [dateComponents setMonth:[dateComponents month]];
                [dateComponents setDay:[dateComponents day]];
                [dateComponents setHour:18];
                [dateComponents setMinute:0];



                UIDatePicker *dd = [[UIDatePicker alloc]init];
                [dd setDate:[gregCalendar dateFromComponents:dateComponents]];

                UILocalNotification *notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc]init];
                notification.alertBody = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",self.date,self.city];
                notification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
                notification.repeatInterval = 0;
                [notification setFireDate:dd.date];
                [notification setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone  defaultTimeZone]];
                [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notification];

}
```

Comment: how are you setting self.city?

Comment: I already solved this

Comment: what was the solution?